# How to catch Access Violation exception in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compact-framework, access-violation

While running a managed application with CF3.5 in WEC7, sometimes it throws Access Violation exception in 2 cases.

**1. USB Barcode scan into a text box field**:
In this case, we are using a user dialog with text box field where Barcode data is scanned using a USB scanner, which recognizes similar to keybaords's keypress event and the data is sent to the text field. This is taken care by .net framework. In some cases it leads to the below exception.

**Screenshot:**
[Error during BarcodeScan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVXfh.png)

**2. Accessing TCPIP socket**:
In this case there is a usage of local RPC connection made using TCP.

**Screenshot:**
[Error in TCP Socket usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw4cY.png)

I have used try..catch for general System.Exceptions, as well as empty catch, to catch all the native exceptions too. But it doesn't catches this exception at all.

```
try
        {
            unsafe
            {
                GetExceptionFrom.GetExceptionFromInternal();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception occured");
        }
```

.Net CF 3.5 supports only *AppDomain.UnhandledException* event, which is also subscribed in Program.cs.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UnhandledException");
        }
```

But this also does not help in catching the AV exception.
Only .Net 4.0 supports HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute which will allow to catch such corrupt exceptions. 
Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: First, the USB HID input exception is thrown by ShowModalDialog and very weired. Without the code, it is hard to say, why you get an exception. Similar for the Socket Exception stuff, without code that will be hard to help to avoid. From MSDN froum : "Unfortunately there's no way to catch native exception on NETCF (unlike on desktop which maps some of them on to managed exceptions which developer can catch)."

Comment: **Thanks for your response.** Yes I also searched related to this kind of AV exceptions, which could not be caught from NETCF. The ShowModalDialog does nothing rather than it has opened a user dialog as Modal. I call Form.ShowDialog() which intern calls this Win API call. But the Exception occurs only when a USB barcode data is read into the textbox field and suddenly it crashes. But this also doesnot happen too frequent. Looks stranger for me.

Comment: If the Exception is only thrown on Barcode Reader Input you should check your Input handling (keypress, keydown,keyup? or TextChanged?). I assume there is no exception when you scan into Notepad/wordpad?!

Comment: Actually the input from the barcode reader gets transmitted to the text box field through Microsoft internal native dlls but we are not handling through the Keypress events. There is some memory management issue within the OS (WEC7) itself which produces the Access violation exception, but could not get any solution to handle this, even in any web search.

Comment: When will you post the code? And the model and manuf. of the scanner?

Comment: There seems to be a memory management issue in the OS side, and we were talking with the customers to resolve it from the Microsoft side through any patch. So thanks for your support. Since the code is not allowed to be shared outside, One reproduction step is by using a C++ project with statement ((*(int *) 0 = 0) ) to produce the access violation exception. Consuming this C++ project , you can write a manageable C# wrapper and use the function and see.